# PHP foreach with jquery dynamic cloned fields

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script where jquery clones a fieldset box with an building, a floor, and a wing (input fields) The user can create as many of these fieldsets as they need.  What I am trying to figure out is this.

I need to main the areas together otherwise I could just loop throug the aray like this.

```
   foreach ($_POST[$key] as $itemvalue)       { 
         $message .= "\n".$key. " : ".$itemvalue; 
      }
```

My first thought was to do this, but of course this was dumb of me

```
foreach ($_POST['building'] as $value) {
    $count++;
    $message .="\n Area" . $count;
    $message .= "\n Building: ". $value;
    foreach ($_POST['floor'] as $value2){
    $message .= "\n Floor: ". $value2;
        }
    foreach ($_POST['wing'] as $value3){
    $message .= "\n Wing: ". $value3;
        }
    }
```

as it just ends up putting each of the floors and wings under every building instead of keep them separate.

my next thought was to put them into one long for each separated by and && symbol, but apparently foreach doesn't work this way.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?

@stewie I made the modifications you suggested, but I am pretty sure this won't work.

```
foreach ($_POST['floor'] as $value)
    { $floor = $value; }
foreach ($_POST['wing'] as $value2) { $wing = $value2; }
foreach ($_POST['building'] as $value3)
    { $building = $value3; $building .= $floor; $building .= $wing; }
```

This is my entire code, the output I am trying to get is this

Area #1
Building : Building 1
Floor : 2
Wing : East

Area #2
Building : Building 2
Floor : 5
Wing : North

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$mailto = "me@myemail.com"; 
$subject = "form"; 
$message = "Values submitted from web site form:"; 
$header = "From: Jeremiah <Jeremiah@myemail.com>"; 

foreach ($_POST['floor'] as $value)
```

{

```
$floor = "\nFloor : " . $value;
}

 foreach ($_POST['wing'] as $value2)
 {
$wing = "\nWing : ".$value2;
 }

 foreach ($_POST['building'] as $value3)
 {
$building = "\n\nBuilding " . $value3;
$building .= $floor ;
$building .= $wing;
$message .= $building;
}




 mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header); 
 }
```

?>

Comment: What's the problem here?  This code works fine?  What output are you getting, and what output do you want?

Comment: @stewie, @rocket I have posted the entire script and an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I thought about $floor and wing into arrays, but that just puts me back into a circle.

Comment: Here is a link to the form I am using if it will help 
http://thatmediaguy.com/keyform/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dirty, but keeping up with your original design !

```
  foreach ($_POST['building'] as $value) {
        $count++;
        $message ="\n Area" . $count;
        $message .= "\n Building: ". $value;
        $message2='';
        foreach ($_POST['floor'] as $value2){
        $message2 .= "\n Floor: ". $value2;
            }
        foreach ($_POST['wing'] as $value3){
        $message2 .= "\n Wing: ". $value3;
          }
    echo $message;
    echo $message2;
            }

        }
```

What you should do is this:

```
foreach(floor){set  $floor} 
foreach(wing) {set $wing}
```

Main foreach

```
foreach(building)
{
   $building = ...
   $building .= $floor
   $building .= $wing
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to PHP and I am not following.  I still need a way to join each group under one field.  Lets say I have a field called area, under each area there is building, floor, and wing.

Comment: There has got to a simpler way of doing this, from what I am looking at with the code you provide, is that I still have to create an array out of the data I collected from each foreach loop.

Comment: All it ends up doing is grabbing the first value entered for floor and wing.  Building of course works fine.

Comment: you haven't concatenated the floor and wing variables.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: everytime I do it that way, I get 4 floors and 4 wings under each building

Comment: I just need them to group, there has to be somewhere I can find information about grouping sets of arrays.

Comment: Because you have $message .= $building; inside the foreach, move it outside the foreach. Please re-read your code.

Comment: I fixed that, but it doesn't group them.  It ends up creating something like this 

building 1 | building 2 | building 3 | floor 1 | floor 2 | floor 3 | wing 1 | wing2 | wing 3  when what I want is something like this building 1 | floor 1 | wing 1 | building 2 | floor 2 | wing 2

If I was going to do it that way, it would be much easier to write the code like this 

      foreach ($_POST[$key] as $itemvalue)
   { 
         
   $message .= "\n".$key. " : ".$itemvalue; 
      }

Comment: Can someone please explain this to me in english... please

Comment: Never mind I solved it using a more elegant for loop.  I will provide that answer tomorrow when the site lets me. There is no wonder that I couldn't get foreach to work and I can't understand why people were responding when this wasn't possible.